# viewport problem

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I want to fit my page on the screen, whatever resolution is there and not allowing scaling.
I have seen in alot of documents/resource that this is the best way of using viewport to adjust the whole page on the screen. (even jquerymobile generate this viewport)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

but It only show some portion of the page.

But this code works as excpected. The whole page is fit on the screen

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0;" />
```

Whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `meta` tag requires that your document width is device width. jQuery Mobile uses it because jQuery Mobile make sure that it will adjust document width according to device width. If you want to put a 980px wide page in a 320px wide screen, then you have to set 980px in the `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980, user-scalable=no">
```

If you don't know your document width, you have to get it first and then set the `meta` tag property.